# Error while processing package, Xcode to ItunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to send an archive to Itunes Connect from Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105), i cant change the provisioning profile from XC to mine, i have been facing this since yesterday. i tried keep changing the provisioning profile from xcodeproj setting but nothing work either.
I thought apple was down, but maybe something else is the culprit?

[image: trying to send archive to Itunes Connect, i cant change the provisioning profile from XC to mine]

[image]

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue buddy ? I am facing same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to change package name from your project build settings to the name of your project. Package name should be same as application name.

Comment: it has been the same forever, i had no problem submitting before for months, and suddenly i just recompile and change the version, then it fails

Comment: You need to update your java environment. I had the jdk 1.6.0 installed and got the same error. After upgrading to jdk 1.8.0 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) the errors are gone.